# Accordion style content

Tags: jquery, css

I've successfully made an accordian that opens and closes when you click on the headings.  My problem is I can't figure out how to make it so that only one part can be open at a time.  Because as it is now they just keep opening and then run off the page.  Is it possible to be able to make it so when one is open and another one is clicked the new one opens and the old one closes?

here's the jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/oxjhva6a/

the code follows this pattern:

```
$('#accordianhead1').toggle(
    function () {
        $('#accordianbody1').animate({
             height: "110"
        }, 500);
        $('#open1').hide();
        $('#close1').show();
    },
    function () {
        $('#accordianbody1').animate({
             height: "0"
        }, 500);
        $('#open1').show();
        $('#close1').hide();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the code is very repetitive. I would instead, get all elements via the class, in your case 'accordionbody' and then hide all elements that are not the element you want to show, and then show the current element.

Using $('.accordionbody') will return you an array of elements, which you can manipulate as you need.

From this, you can close all accordions on click, and then show just the clicked one.

This can be done like so:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.accordianhead').on('click', function(elem) {
            console.log('running');
            $('.accordianbody').hide()
            $(elem.target).closest('.accordianhead').next().height('120px').show()
        });
    });
```

I updated your plunkr for you

http://jsfiddle.net/oxjhva6a/2/

Comment: That worked great!  Thank you for your help!  That's always my problem:  trying to use less repetitive code.

Answer (score 0):

As @Lou said, the code can be simplified by selecting all `.accordionhead` once.

I fixed your code and keeps animations as the original example.

http://jsfiddle.net/h8bj91xc/1/

Please see comments on code.

```js
$('.accordianhead').on('click',
    function (e) {
        // close all others animated
        $('.accordianbody').not($(this).next()).animate({
            height: "0"
        }, 500);
        // show all open and hide all close
        $('.open').show();
        $('.close').hide();
        // open next element animated, i mean .accordianbody
        $(this).next().animate({
            height: "110"
        }, 500);
        // hidden children .open and show children .close
        $(this).find('.open').hide();
        $(this).find('.close').show();
    }
);
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 outline:0px;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
#accordian
{
    margin:20px auto 0 auto;
    width:98%;
}

.accordianhead
{
    cursor:pointer;
    width:100%;
    height:35px;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #575757;
background: #1c1c1c; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1c1c1c 0%, #3a3a3a 48%, #1c1c1c 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1c1c1c), color-stop(48%,#3a3a3a), color-stop(100%,#1c1c1c)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1c1c1c 0%,#3a3a3a 48%,#1c1c1c 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1c1c1c 0%,#3a3a3a 48%,#1c1c1c 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1c1c1c 0%,#3a3a3a 48%,#1c1c1c 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1c1c1c 0%,#3a3a3a 48%,#1c1c1c 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1c1c1c', endColorstr='#1c1c1c',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

.accordianhead h2
{
    color:White;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:Century gothic;
    padding:9px;
    float:left;
}

.accordianhead h2:hover
{
    color:#FF8000;
}

.accordianbody
{
    width:100%;
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */

}

.accordianbody p
{
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Arial;
    color:#303030;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:1.3em;
}

.open
{
    float:right;
    color:White;
    padding:9px;
}
.close
{
    float:right;
    color:White;
    padding:9px;
    display:none;
}

.accordianbody h3
{
    text-align:left;
    font-family:Arial;
    color:#212121;
    font-size:16px;
    padding:3px;
    margin-left:5px;
}

.accordianbody h4
{
    text-align:left;
    font-family:Arial;
    color:#303030;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:3px;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordian">
<div class="accordianhead" id="accordianhead1"><h2>Customer Service/Pricing</h2><h6 class="open" id="open1">Open +</h6><h6 class="close" id="close1">Close -</h6></div>
<div class="accordianbody" id="accordianbody1"><h3>McFarland Door & Millwork, LLC</h3><h4>July 2014 – November 2014 | Lakeview,OR</h4><p>Received, priced, and delivered all quotes with a 24 hour turn around time goal. Trained others in the quoting department and consulted with the owners on hiring. Customer service: answered technical questions, problem solving, and building relationships with customers to increase sales.</p></div>
<div class="accordianhead" id="accordianhead2"><h2>Web Designer/Developer</h2><h6 class="open" id="open2">Open +</h6><h6 class="close" id="close2">Close -</h6></div>
<div class="accordianbody" id="accordianbody2"><h3>McFarland Door Mfg. Co., Inc.</h3><h4>January 2013 – April 2013 | Lakeview, OR</h4><p>Designed and developed new website from the ground up and managed social networking.</p></div>
<div class="accordianhead" id="accordianhead3"><h2>Administrative Assistant</h2><h6 class="open" id="open3">Open +</h6><h6 class="close" id="close3">Close -</h6></div>
<div class="accordianbody" id="accordianbody3"><h3>McFarland Door Mfg. Co., Inc.</h3><h4>June 2011 – September 2012 | Lakeview, OR</h4><p>Answered phones, typed quotes, did all shipping paperwork for daily shipments, entered bills, basic accounting, calculated sales commissions, worked with Microsoft word, and Excel, re-designed company invoices, was the go-to person for anything that needed to be done.</p></div>
<div class="accordianhead" id="accordianhead4"><h2>Small Business Owner</h2><h6 class="open" id="open4">Open +</h6><h6 class="close" id="close4">Close -</h6></div>
<div class="accordianbody" id="accordianbody4"><h3>Savannah Poultry</h3><h4>May 2009 – March 2012 | Lakeview, OR</h4><p>Built the business up from the very beginnings of the idea stage all the way to being a thriving company. Totally created and built website and company brand. Did all marketing and customer service. Raised all stock carefully managing genetics, breeding, etc. Initiated all hatching procedures and development of new breeds. Packaged and shipped products all across the United States.</p></div>
<div class="accordianhead" id="accordianhead5"><h2>Veterinary Technician</h2><h6 class="open" id="open5">Open +</h6><h6 class="close" id="close5">Close -</h6></div>
<div class="accordianbody" id="accordianbody5"><h3>Lakeview Animal Hospital</h3><h4>September 2009 – August 2010 | Lakeview, OR</h4><p>Assisted Doctors during exams, surgeries, procedures etc. Office work: filing, answering phones, etc. Stocked and checked in inventory. Took care of animals that were boarding including walking, feeding, and giving medications. Went on house calls with doctors to assist in handling of patients. Other various tasks that are common in the Veterinary field.</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was trying to accomplish right now.  (without much luck, haha)  Thank you so much!  You guys rock.

Comment: @user3880230 don't forget accept an answer if you fell that answer your question. Enjoy!